# Is it possible to do a chromakey in a VideoView in Android

Tags: android, transparency, android-videoview, chromakey

I am searching for a way to make certain colors in an android VideoView transparent like is shown in this HTML5 example:
http://www.tinkernut.com/demos/273_chroma/video_chroma.html

Here they specify range of rgb values that for each pixel in each frame of the video to be transparent.

I have experimented with setApha, but I seem to only be able to control the opacity of the all colors in in the frame, not make a certain color transparent.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.